# Probability question - finding the minimum number of people at an event of 100

Tags: probability

At an event, 100 people are invited. 50% are coming alone and the rest will bring either 1 or 2 plus ones. What is the minimum number of 6 people tables that should be at booked at the event?

So, I'm confused on what it should be.

If I assume that 50 people are single, and the other 50 only bring 1 extras, then the total will be 150, giving us 25 tables. And if I assume, that there is a probability of 50/50 for plus 1 or 2, then there will be 75 extra, which would then be a total of 175, so ~30 tables. Or take the max number of people, 200 and so the minimum number of tables would be 34 tables.

Which should be correct?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions allow for the case of 50 alone and 50 with 2 guests, or $50 + 50 \cdot 3 = 200$.  So you need $\lceil \frac{200}{6} \rceil = 34$.

Comment: 200/6, so 34 tables should be the minimum number of tables?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The "minimum" means the minimum in the worst-case scenario, which is just your "maximum".